# Matching Product Prices from an HTML text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying a simple regex on a string for pricing information, but my `preg_match_all` is simply not finding what it should.

I'm looking for instance of e.g. `$**.**` or `£**.**` or sometimes the currency symbol might be encoded as an HTML entity e.g. for GBP `&pound;` or `&#163;`

Is there an issue with using `preg_match_all` to find html entities?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$price = preg_match_all(
    '#(?:\$|\£|\€|\&pound;|\&#163;)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)#', 
    $string, 
    $matches
);
```

But I get: Unknown modifier '1'

Comment: Don't downvote without comments please  - what's wrong with the question?

Comment: You should be aware that in some countries, the currency symbol comes after the price. See also a regex there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517468/php-regular-expression-to-match-price-or-amount

Comment: @MarvinLabs - Hi, yes I am aware of that of course, the post you show does not regex for currency only a number, the string being searched may also contain numbers which are not currency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some obvious errors:

**1)** `preg_match_all()` expects at least 3 parameters, so it has to be

```
preg_match_all(
    '#(?:\$|\£|\€|\&pound;|\&#163;)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)#', 
    $string, 
    $matches
);
```

The `$matches` variable will contain the matched strings. Your `$price` will contain the number of times the pattern matched. Please see http://php.net/preg_match_all for further information.

**2)** You have an unescaped delimiter:

```
'#(?:\$|\£|\€|\&pound;|\&#163;)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)#'
 ^                       ^                    ^
 Start                   Unescaped            End
```

Fixing these two issues will make the [code run without any parsing errors](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AbEh7a). It should also answer your literal question about matching entities.

However, I somewhat doubt the Regex achieves what you are trying to do. Prices are not always listed `[CurrencySymbol][Amount]`. For instance, Euros are usually written as 100€ or 100 €. So you'd have to check for digits before the symbols and whitespace after as well.

Comment: Gonna accept this answer as the more I think about this the more I think it's just the wrong way to do it anyway! Thanks for your help/advice, it is appreciated.