# Matching pricing from html - regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matching Product Prices from an HTML text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686350/matching-product-prices-from-an-html-text)

I have a string which is usually, but not always, html page source

I want to extract pricing from within the string. I know this is not an exact science and the combination of currency symbol placement etc is endless but anything better than nothing.

example string:

```
$string = 'the price is <tag>&#163;10.00</tag>';
```

So, I am starting with the following regex:

```
$price = preg_match('#(?:\$|\£|\€|\&pound;|\&\#163;)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)#', $string);
```

But of course this only returns the first character.

My question is, is there a way keep going through $string until it finds a certain character? e.g. < or a space? and then return what was found which in this case would be: 10.00

Is this a feasible way of doing this or is there a better way?

Here's the above in an example:

http://ideone.com/u8erb

Comment: you have html source & from that source you need to pick price ?

Comment: What do you mean it only returns the first character?  You're not even inspecting matches

Comment: @ExplosionPills this is what I mean http://ideone.com/u8erb

Comment: @GBD The post says this:  I have a string which is usually, but not always, html page source. I want to extract pricing from within the string. So, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs for `preg_match`, it does not return your match, it only returns if there was a match.

Try this

```
$string = 'the price is <tag>&#163;10.00</tag>';

$price = preg_match_all('#(?:\$|\£|\€|\&pound;|\&\#163;)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)#', $string, $matches);

//This will contain your matches 
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `preg_match_all` with `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=<\s*/\s*tag\s*>)`, since the currency may change? Any solution with regex will depend on a set of assumptions, so it's good to get those down first:

- Where should you be looking, are these prices occurring within a given div?
- What is the full set of possible values?

Try to make your regex as broad as possible, since a common reason it'll fail in the future is because something minor has changed which you haven't considered. If these prices are occurring in a tag with ids and classes, consider using an XHTML parser instead:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/